# Webgl: Textures get mixed between different vbo's

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I can successfully render a plane with a texture but when I draw multiple objects with different textures then they "randomly" start to mix textures between each other.

[image]

My goal is to render sprites. I have one vbo that is just a flat surface that changes texture for each rendering.

This is my rendering function: "spritePlan" is the vbo of a plane vertices texture coord etc.

```
gl.uniform2fv(shaderProgram.texScalerUniform, [subImageWidth/object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.mergedImages.width, 1]);
gl.uniform2fv(shaderProgram.texOffsetUniform, [object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.mergedImagesPositions[object.spriteIndex]/object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.mergedImages.width, 0]);



gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.vertBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribLocation, spritePlan.vertBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.texCoordBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(textureCoordAttribute, spritePlan.texCoordBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.colorBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(colorAttribLocation, spritePlan.colorBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.textureSprite);
gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.sampler2DUniform, 0);

gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, spritePlan.indexBuffer);
setMatrixUniforms();



var xPos = Math.round(object.x-object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.originX - viewXP)/rooms[gameVariables.currentRoom].roomWidth,
    yPos = Math.round(object.y-object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.originY - viewYP)/rooms[gameVariables.currentRoom].roomHeight;

var scaleX = (object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.width/2)/rooms[gameVariables.currentRoom].roomWidth;
var scaleY = (object.objectTypeMetaData.sprite.height/2)/rooms[gameVariables.currentRoom].roomHeight;
mat4.identity(mvMatrix);



mat4.scale(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [scaleX, scaleY, 1]);

mat4.translate(mvMatrix, mvMatrix, [(xPos/scaleX), (1/scaleY)-(yPos/scaleY), 0.0]);
gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, spritePlan.indexBuffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 fragColor;
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;
void main()
{
    vec4 tex = texture2D(uSampler, vTextureCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0) * vec4(tex.rgb, tex.a);
};
```

This is my fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;
attribute vec3 vertPosition;
attribute vec3 vertColor;
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;
varying vec3 fragColor;
varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;
uniform mat4 uPMatrix;
uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;

uniform vec2 uvOffset;
uniform vec2 uvScale;

void main()
{
    fragColor = vertColor;
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(vertPosition.x, vertPosition.y, vertPosition.z, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord =  (vec4(aTextureCoord, 0, 1)).xy * uvScale + uvOffset;
};
```

I don't really know what may cause this. Every sprite texture is associated with an object and a "new Image" and I looked and every texture is associated with the right object.

Am I not binding the textures correctly? What might be the problem?

**Edit1:**

<strike>I have noticed a pattern in how the textures are replaced.They just switch one step to the sprite that executes after it, so instead of rendering "1 2 3" it renders "3 1 2" which tells me this might be a really easy problem which makes much more frustrating :S</strike>

Each sprite is an object with their own Image. My canvas renderer tells me that each sprite has their correct image accosiated with them, so it's probably where I convert their image to a texture where something wrong happens. However I can't see any problems with my image to texture converter:

```
for(var i=0; i<spritesCompiled.length; i++){
    spritesCompiled[i].textureSprite = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, spritesCompiled[i].textureSprite);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL,true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D,0,gl.RGBA,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, spritesCompiled[i].mergedImages);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D,null);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Are you sure it should look like the left image? Like you didn't just get your textures mixed up? (sorry I know that's a dumb question it's just I don't see anything in the code you posted). Where's the code that uploads the image to the textures? Maybe you forgot to bind the correct texture before uploading? Maybe you didn't [*close* over the correct variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) and your `image.onload` function is using the wrong values?

Comment: Im pretty sure I havn't mixed the images, I have a canvas renderar that renders the images correctly. But I can taket another look at it. I'll have to do it lager though as I am away from my computer att the moment

Comment: I've taken a closer look and edited the post now